# Querydsl jpa getting started

Tags: maven, querydsl

I am new to jsf and java and now building web project with jsf, using jpa and jpql.
Now in my project to write jpql query I do like this:

```
 Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Advert as a where a.razdel like ?1 and a.categoryId like ?2"    );
```

But I have read that query dsl is much more better and convient in using.
So I've read some tutorials and found there this:

```
Add the following dependencies to your Maven project and make sure that the Maven 2 repo of Mysema Source (http://source.mysema.com/maven2/releases) is accessible from your POM :



<dependency>
  <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
  <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
  <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>    

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
  <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
  <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But where to add this setting?
In my project I just have web.xml, persistence.xml and that's all?

Comment: It's Maven. So learn [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) or find an other tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add this in the file `pom.xml` in the  section like this:

```
<dependencies>
  // add the stuff here
</dependencies>
```

To make this work you probably have to define the value for `${querydsl.version}` in a `<property>`. This should look similar to this:

```
<properties>
    <querydsl.version>THE_REAL_VERSION_NUMBER</querydsl.version>
</properties>
```

It looks like you also have to add the repository where the files can be downloaded:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Mysema Source</id>
        <name>Mysema Source - Releases</name>
        <url>http://source.mysema.com/maven2/releases)</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

If you don't have a `pom.xml`, you don't have a Maven based project. If this is the case you really should read a basic Maven tutorial.

If you don't want to use Maven, you can also manually download the required library jar files and put them in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your web application.